# error in specific category loop

Tags: categories, loop

I want to show my specific category's last 3 post. I created this loop but it is showing only one post. What to do?[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have at least 3 posts that belong to the news category? Are those posts published?

Comment: yes bro.. all are published

Answer (score 0):

Using `query_posts` is asking for trouble, because its results may be unpredictable (read more about that in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)). In stead you should define a new query and loop through its results. Like this:

```
$args = array( 
    'category_name' => 'news',
    'posts_per_page' => '3'
    );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        the_content();
        }
    }
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: try with this bro. and its showing only last 1 post.. i need last 3 post

Comment: That means either there are no three posts or something is using the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the query.

Comment: there are 5 posts. can you please help me out bro.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to do your debugging yourself, because there are too many possible sources of interference. Switch off all plugins, switch to a different theme. and see what happens